# Class<type> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I have a class and want to work with it as Lists: e.g. `List<int>, List<string>, ... , List<T>`
I have a class Randomizor which will take the collection data type that will be shuffled. How can I do so?

```
class Randomizor<T>
{
    public Randomizor()
    {

    }

    public Array Shuffle(Array toShuffle)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: As a side-note; The correct spelling is "Randomiser", or "Randomizer" ( in American English )

Comment: Don't you actually want an extender of IEnumerable<T>, called Shuffle, that will return a randomly reordered IEnumerable<T>? If not, what will the rest of the class do?

Comment: @Uw Concept, so the correct spelling is Randomiser :-)

Comment: Hahahahaha! Fabulous comment @Jodrell

Comment: @Jodrell : I want to add this extention

Comment: At the risk of being a language bore, Randomization is correct English, Randomisation is not (its some other langauge). Oops.

Comment: Improved answer with more reasearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: I found two superior impementations after a little digging so I would suggest those in preference.**

An extension method for this purpose and already been suggested previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412405/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-these-two-algorithms-for-shuffling-an-i)
I include the code paraphrased to Shuffle below.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source)
{     
    Random random = new Random ();     
    T [] copy = source.ToArray ();      
    for (int i = copy.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {         
        int index = random.Next (i + 1);
        yield return copy [index];
        copy [index] = copy [i];
    }
}
```

---

And an interesting solution adapted from this [linq approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254573/can-you-enumerate-a-collection-in-c-out-of-order/254605#254605)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T> (this IEnumerable<T> source)
{     
    Random random = new Random ();     
    return source.OrderBy(i => Random.Next()).AsEnumerable();
}
```

---

[The orignal answer but slower than the edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254573/can-you-enumerate-a-collection-in-c-out-of-order/254664#254664)

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) 
{     
    Random random = new Random();
    List<T> copy = sequence.ToList();
    while (copy.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = random.Next(copy.Count);
        yield return copy[index];
        copy.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

If you like one of these you should up vote the linked answer.

If you are very concerned about randomness, you could upgrade to one of the [RNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) algorithms from the Crypto API and seed it with some non deterministic value, like somthing generated from recent mouse activity. I suspect that would be overkill and it would degrade performance.

Comment: As noted in the comments of the original answer this algorithm has higher complexity than needed because of the use of RemoveAt for a list.

Answer (score 3):

Create a generic class like so:

```
class Randomizer<TList, TType> where TList : IList<TType>
{
    public TList Randomize(TList list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or like so:

```
class Randomizer<T>
{
    public IList<T> Randomize(IList<T> list)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Left to the OP. I think his question was about how to use generics in that case, not how to really implement the randomizing...

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear question... do you mean something like this?

```
public static class Randomizer<T>
{
   public static T GetRandom(List<T> list)
   {
      T value = default(T);
      // Perform some random logic.

      return value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Approximately. But will T return a collection ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Randomizor<T>
{
    public Randomizor()
    {

    }

    public List<T> Shuffle(List<T> toShuffle)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Randomizer<T>
{
    public Randomizer(ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        //Do something with collection using T as the type of the elements
    }            
}
```

However you may want to go for a generic extension method

```
static class Randomizer
{
    public static void Randomize<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        //randomize the collection
    }
}
```

and the usage:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
list.Randomize();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the following algorithm : have a list of int stores the available places. Put the content of a random index in the result collection. Delete the index from available places. How Can I return this result, please?

Comment: Well just make the method return a new collection instead of doing the shuffle in place (like my method signature suggests)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this:

```
    public List<T> Shuffle<T>(List<T> toShuffle)
    {
        return toShuffle.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    }
```

Or as an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> toShuffle)
    {
        return toShuffle.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because ordering by random does not yield even distribution? Let me downvote you too:)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/01/31/spot-the-defect-bad-comparisons-part-four.aspx

Comment: What part of the question even mentioned 'even distribution'?

Comment: OK but lets agree that an exception or infinite loop is not desired effect for any question on stack overflow even if it does not explicitly state that, shall we? :)

Comment: I have no problem if the code I provided is incorrect. But I can not see where it would cause an infinite loop

Comment: Did you read the article I linked in my comment because it explains why it can go in an infinite loop (though it probably won't)?

Comment: Did you read my code? It doesn't use the Sort method, it uses OrderBy, so even if Guid.NewGuid() did happen somehow to produce a duplicate it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Unless OrderBy documentation specifies that the selector function is called exactly once for each element and the result is somehow cached for use when a new comparison is required this implementation is wrong. Duplicates do not matter. What matters is that if X is compared to Y once and then it is compared to Y again the result should be the same. If your selector function is called several times it can produce inconsistent results.

Comment: So you now agree that the code I provided would not cause an infinite loop or an exception? Yes the selector function will produce inconsistent results, but all the OP ask for a list of its to be shuffled.. and that is what my code does.

Comment: No I don't agree. If the elements are let's say ints and the sorting algorithm used by OrderBy compares let's say 3 and 5 and it needs to compare it again (because sorting algorithms compare elements more than once) and your implementation (NewGuid()) returns a greater guid for 3 the first time and a greater guid for 5 the second time then the behaviour is undefined and the code can throw an exception or run infinitely.

Comment: An example of a valid sorting algorithm that can run practically infinitely is Bubble Sort (you know Bubble Sort, right?) What if the implementation raised a flag when a swap is done and checked this flag at the end of each iteration to see if the sorting is done. Then your "NewGuid()" comparison implementation would produce different guids every time and almost always there would be a swap more so if the list is large. However if your implementation did conform to the rule of every sorting algorithm that the comparison should be stable it would surely finish in at most N(O^2) time

Comment: If you look at the code for OrderedEnumerable you will see that the situation you describe should never occur as the provided key selector is evaluated for each element before the sort takes place. (and yes I have heard of a bubble sort once or twice)

Comment: @Dve can you guarantee that the implementation won't change in the next version of the framework? Relying on undocumented, non-pubic implementation details is skating on thin ice.

Comment: @Phoog by that rational we shouldn't be using .NET at all!

Comment: @Dve unless it is documented you should not depend on it but this is actually a valid argument (unlike your other arguments) if it was guaranteed by the documentation. I will take back my downvote because of it :) ... but my vote is locked for some amount of hours :(